# php mysql select only last 3 rows if they are similar and updated 15 minutes earlier

Tags: php, mysql, gps

my table is as follows:

**scene at 2016-03-24 11:41 hrs:**
I am receiving SMS messages at interval of 5 minutes from the GPS tracker and inserting in db. the challenge is to issue  commands to wake up and put into sleep mode the GPS tracker depending upon result of query.

```
id   |   snd_sms_time   |    lat  |   lng  
41750|2016-03-24 11:40:0|26.215363|84.888593   
41749|2016-03-24 11:35:0|26.215363|84.888593  
41748|2016-03-24 11:30:0|26.215363|84.888593     
41747|2016-03-24 11:25:0|26.215363|84.888593
```

the mysql query should return last 3 rows having same lat. and long. All the  lat. and long. are similar it means the loco car is standing still for the last 15 minutes so that now i can put the GPS tracker in sleep mode  for time interval of 15 minutes to conserve battery.

**scene at 2016-03-24 12:00 hrs:**

i now wake up the GPS tracker at time after 15 minutes at 2016-03-24 11:56 hrs.(i have put the GPS tracker in sleep mode at 11:41 hrs) The lat. and long. are different for the 3 rows (id: 41751,41750,41749)

```
 id  |   snd_sms_time   |    lat  |   lng  
41751|2016-03-24 11:59:0|26.215370|84.888593   
41750|2016-03-24 11:40:0|26.215363|84.888593  
41749|2016-03-24 11:35:0|26.215363|84.888593     
41748|2016-03-24 11:30:0|26.215363|84.888593
```

now the query should return 0 rows because the position has changed. any ideas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using `exists` and `subquery`.

```
select * from message 
where exists(
    select 1 
    from (select * from message order by snd_sms_time DESC limit 3) t 
    group by lat,lng 
    having count(*) = 3
    )
order by snd_sms_time DESC limit 3;
```

Comment: thanks dylan. it worked. copy +paste .but still not able to understand the query